# How we do better performance and unload unnecessary selectors?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Somehow we need to extract from `css` files just specific selectors for better performance! For example, `#javascript` and `#idea` from a css file with 540 selectors. We need just the selectors which is called from `#html`and `#page`.
Any clever js code?

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="whatever">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Another Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" required> <!-- Required Core Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="interface-elements.css" partial> <!-- The interface -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- From interface-elements.css we need to load in browser only next elements. Even file contain 540 selectors ! -->

<!-- Let's extract just 3 selectors :
 .btn
 .title 
 .dropcap -->
<button class="btn">Do something</button>
<h1 class="title">Huh</h1>
<p><span class="dropcap">L</span>orem ipsum Bla bla bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can we do that in an better way?

You have 2 css files `button.css` which contains core button style and `colors.css` which contain a set of colors. You call in your html page `<a class="btn btn-primary"></a>` and the browser load all your color classes `danger`, `primary` , `success` etc . You understand what I mean?

Comment: Why you don't use IDE search(e.g. Notepadd++)

Comment: check these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS, https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/, http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: the truth is some css selectors take longer time to be searched e.g selectors having attributes and attributes pattern matching, or general sibling selectors, the most efficient would be id selectors and class selectors, check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618138/what-happened-to-the-use-efficient-css-selectors-rule

Comment: Yes i know that ! But for example : You have 2 css files `button.css` wich contain core button style and  `colors.css` wich contain an set of colors. You call in your html page `<a class="btn btn-primary"></a>` and the browser load all your color classes `danger`, `primary`, `success` etc . You understand what i mean ?

Comment: @RobertAdrianBogdan, yes i see, but that depends on whether new elemnts with new (unused) classes may be added dynamicaly in the page, else if everything is static and hardcoded it would be easy to load only the styles used, e.g via a tailor-made css stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

A unnecessary selectors is a selector that is never used, but the website is dynamic so there is no programatic way to find out.

Use the plugin "unusedCSS" for chrome to find out what selector is maybe never used.

Comment: I remember the Canoo-Webtests gives infos about unused selectors.

Comment: I need an javascript script wich do that : Analyze css file, analyze html code  and from existing css file, generate temporary css file with only " called selectors" ... And that file will be loaded in browser ( JUST AN IDEA )

Comment: Why javascript? Do you like to send a statistic about used selectors to a server?